# How to correctly handle event with dynamically added elements?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am developing a ToDo app with HTML and JS, while got stuck with removing dynamically added elements. Is there any way to remove the selected element?

I have tried to delete an element via selecting its parent and then reaching to the child and removing it. Could not arrange to remove the selected element though. `el.removeChild(el.childNodes[0])` removes the element from the beginning. Is there any way to remove the selected-active element?

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.id== 'rem'){
    let el = document.getElementById('uList');
    el.removeChild(el.childNodes[0]); // How to remove the clicked el?
   }
});
```

I expect the code to remove the clicked element, rather deleting the nodes starting from the 0 element.

Many thanks!

Comment: is "el" the whole list(the whole <ul/>)?  and what is "rem"(its id for ul or li? ) can you provide the html structure  , then it will be helpful? FYI: if el is a <ul/> element then el.childNode[0] will remove its first <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target || e.target.id !== 'rem') {
        return;
    }
    let parent = e.target.parentElement;
    if (!!parent) {
        parent.removeChild(e.target);
    }
});
```

for the parent of parent:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target || e.target.id !== 'rem') {
        return;
    }
    const parent = e.target.parentElement;
    if (!parent) {
        return;
    }
    const parentOfParent = parent.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(e.target);
    if (!!parentOfParent) {
        parentOfParent.removeChild(parent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks!! Could you also specify, how I can remove the parent of the selected element?

Comment: `parentOfClickedElement = clickedElement.parentElement;
parentOfParentOfClickedElement = parentOfClickedElement.parentElement;`

Comment: Many thanks my friend, solved my problem completely! :)